# Prisma, graphql and react hook forms: how to use created values in update form mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, prisma, react-hook-form

I am trying to make a form that has to create and update functionality. At the moment, when I get to the update form, I can enter new values and they do save to psql, but the form loads with blank fields instead of the values used to create the existing object. I can't find the settings I need to apply to use the existing object values in the update form so that it loads with the fields displaying the currently saved values.

My form has:

```
import * as React from "react"
import {  CgTrash, CgEditMarkup } from "react-icons/cg"
import { VscIssues } from "react-icons/vsc"

import { gql } from "@apollo/client"
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  ButtonGroup,
  IconButton,
  useDisclosure,
  Wrap,
  Stack,
  Table,
  Tbody,
  Tr,
  Td,
  TableContainer,
  Text
} from "@chakra-ui/react"
import Head from "next/head"
import { useToast } from "lib/hooks/useToast"
import { useForm } from "lib/hooks/useForm"
import { Form } from "components/Form"
import { FormError } from "components/FormError"
import { Input } from "components/Input"
import { Textarea } from "components/Textarea"

import { 
    // IssueGroupInput, 
    useAllIssueGroupsQuery, 
    useCreateIssueGroupMutation, 
    useUpdateIssueGroupMutation,
    useDeleteIssueGroupMutation,  
    IssueGroup as IssueGroupGQLType,  
}  from "lib/graphql"
//
// import { AdminCreateIssueGroupForm } from "components/AdminCreateIssueGroupForm"
// import { AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm } from "components/AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm"
import { AdminLayout } from "components/AdminLayout"
import { AuthedHomeLayout } from "components/AuthedHomeLayout"
import { Modal } from "components/Modal"
import Yup from "lib/yup"


const __ = gql`

  mutation CreateIssueGroup($data: IssueGroupInput!) {
    createIssueGroup(data: $data) {
      id
      title
      
    }
  }  
  query AllIssueGroups {
    allIssueGroups {
      id
      title
    }
  }

  mutation updateIssueGroup($id: String!) {
    updateIssueGroup(id: $id) {
        id
        title
       
    }
  }

  mutation deleteIssueGroup($id: String!) {
    deleteIssueGroup(id: $id) {
      id
      title

    }
  }
`

const IssueGroupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string().required(),
    description: Yup.string().required(),
    // issues: Yup.string()
  })
  

function IssueGroups() {
  const toast = useToast()
  // const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("")
  // const [selectedIssueGroups, setSelectedIssueGroups] = React.useState<string[]>([])
  const modalProps = useDisclosure()
  const modalPropsUpdate = useDisclosure()
//   // const [sort, setSort] = React.useState<Sort>({ createdAt: SortOrder.Desc })
  const [createIssueGroup] = useCreateIssueGroupMutation()
  const [updateIssueGroup] = useUpdateIssueGroupMutation()
  const [deleteIssueGroup] = useDeleteIssueGroupMutation()
  const {  data: issueGroups } = useAllIssueGroupsQuery()
  const defaultValues = {
    title: "",
    description: "",
    // issues: "",
  }
  const form = useForm({ defaultValues, schema: IssueGroupSchema })
  const [selectedIssueGroup, setSelectedIssueGroup ] = React.useState<Omit<
  IssueGroupGQLType,
  "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "issues"
> | null>(null)
  
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

    const onCreateSubmit = async (data: Yup.InferType<typeof IssueGroupSchema>) => {
        return await form.handler(
            () =>
            createIssueGroup({ variables: { data } }),
            {
                onSuccess: async (res, toast) => {
                    // await refetchAllIssueGroups()
                    toast({
                        title: "IssueGroup created",
                        status: "success",
                    })
                    form.reset()
                    onClose()
                }
            }
        )
    }

    const handleUpdateSubmit = async (data: Yup.InferType<typeof IssueGroupSchema>) => {
        console.log(selectedIssueGroup.id)
        return await form.handler(
           
            () =>
           
            updateIssueGroup({ variables: { 
                id: selectedIssueGroup.id, 
                // issues: "none",
                data: { ...data } 
            } }),
        )
    }


    const onDeleteIssueGroup = async (id: string) => {
        return
        form.handler(
            () =>
                deleteIssueGroup({ variables: { id } }),
                {
                onSuccess: async () => {
                await fetch("api/issueGroups", { method: "delete"})
                toast({
                    title: "IssueGroup deleted",
                    status: "success",
                })
                },
                // refetchAllIssueGroups()
            },
        )
    }
  return (
    <Box>
      <Head>
        <title>trying to figure out how to crud in prisma react hook forms</title>
      </Head>

      <Wrap mb={4} spacing={2}>
        <Button
          onClick={modalProps.onOpen}
          leftIcon={<Box boxSize="18px" as={VscIssues} />}
          color="brand.white"
          fontWeight="normal"
          backgroundColor="brand.orange"
          _hover={{
            backgroundColor: "brand.green",
            color: "brand.white",
          }}
        >
          Create issueGroup
        </Button>
      </Wrap>

      <Modal {...modalProps} title="Create IssueGroup">
        {/* <AdminCreateIssueGroupForm onClose={modalProps.onClose} /> */}
        <Form {...form} onSubmit={onCreateSubmit}>
            <Stack>
                <Input name="title" label="Title" />

                {/* <Input name="description" label="Description" /> */}
                {/* <Text mb='8px' fontWeight="medium" fontSize="sm" > Description</Text> */}
                <Textarea name="description" label="Describe" rows={4} />

                <FormError />
                <ButtonGroup>
                <Button onClick={modalProps.onClose}>Cancel</Button>
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    isLoading={form.formState.isSubmitting}
                    isDisabled={form.formState.isSubmitting}
                    color="brand.white"
                    fontWeight="normal"
                    backgroundColor="brand.orange"
                    _hover={{
                    backgroundColor: "brand.green",
                    color: "brand.white",
                    }}
                >
                    Create
                </Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </Stack>
            </Form>
      </Modal>

        <TableContainer maxW="80%">
            <Table variant='simple'>
            <Tbody>
            {issueGroups?.allIssueGroups.map((issueGroup) => (
                <Tr key={issueGroup.id}>

                <Td>
                    <Text textStyle="h6">{issueGroup.title}</Text>

                </Td>
                <Td>
                    <ButtonGroup>
                    <IconButton
                        variant='outline'
                        color="brand.blue"
                        fontWeight="normal"
                        backgroundColor="brand.white"
                        aria-label='Update Issue Group'
                        fontSize='15px'
                        ml={4}
                        icon={<CgEditMarkup />}
                        // onClick={modalPropsUpdate.onOpen}
                        onClick={() => {
                            setSelectedIssueGroup(issueGroup)
                            modalPropsUpdate.onOpen()
                        }}
                        _hover={{
                            backgroundColor: "brand.blue",
                            color: "brand.white",
                        }}
                    />

                    {/* {
                        selectedIssueGroup && isOpen && 
                        <Modal issueGroup={selectedIssueGroup} isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}  title="Edit IssueGroup"  >
                    } */}

                        <Modal {...modalPropsUpdate } title="Edit IssueGroup"  >

                        {/* <AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm
                        onClose={modalPropsUpdate.onClose}
                        issueGroup={selectedIssueGroup} */}
                        {/* /> */}
                            <Form {...form} onSubmit={handleUpdateSubmit}>
                                <Stack>
                                    <Input name="title" label="Title" defaultValue={selectedIssueGroup.title} />

                                  
                                    <Textarea name="description" label="Describe" rows={4} defaultValue={selectedIssueGroup.description} />
```

// I also tried using the defaultValue as issueGroup.title/description, but those don't load the values either. When I try with issueGroup.title, the modal loads with empty fields (there are values saved in psql). When I try with selectedIssueGroup.title, the error message says:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title').

I know there is a title because it renders on the page when I list existing objects. I also know the update is working because I can see psql update.

```
                                    <FormError />
                                    <ButtonGroup>
                                    <Button onClick={modalPropsUpdate.onClose}>Cancel</Button>
                                    <Button
                                        type="submit"
                                        isLoading={form.formState.isSubmitting}
                                        isDisabled={form.formState.isSubmitting}
                                        color="brand.white"
                                        fontWeight="normal"
                                        backgroundColor="brand.orange"
                                        _hover={{
                                        backgroundColor: "brand.green",
                                        color: "brand.white",
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        Save changes
                                    </Button>
                                    </ButtonGroup>
                                </Stack>
                            </Form>
                        </Modal>

                    <IconButton
                        variant='outline'
                        color="brand.tomato"
                        fontWeight="normal"
                        backgroundColor="brand.white"
                        aria-label='Call Sage'
                        fontSize='15px'
                        ml={4}
                        icon={<CgTrash />}
                        onClick={() => onDeleteIssueGroup(issueGroup.id)}
                        _hover={{
                        backgroundColor: "brand.tomato",
                        color: "brand.white",
                        }}
                    />
                    </ButtonGroup>

                </Td>

                </Tr>
                ))}
            </Tbody>

            </Table>
        </TableContainer>

    </Box>
  )
}

IssueGroups.getLayout = (page: React.ReactNode) => <AuthedHomeLayout><AdminLayout>{page}</AdminLayout></AuthedHomeLayout>

export default IssueGroups
```

**ARJUN'S SUGGESTIONS**

I tried each of Arjun's suggestions in his answer below. The results were as follows:

**First suggestion** - being to add a use effect statement to the issues.tsx to try and set the value of issueGroup. To do this, I added this effect beneath the definition of setSelectedIssueGroup:

```
useEffect(()=>{ 
  if(selectedIssueGroup) 
    modalPropsUpdate.onOpen() 
}, [selectedIssueGroup]);
```

When I try this, I get an error in my vsCode that says:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'modalPropsUpdate'.
> Either include it or remove the dependency array.

modalPropsUpdate is defined above that useEffect as:

```
  const modalPropsUpdate = useDisclosure()
```

To address that error, I tried commenting out that line. In that case, the useEffect is:

```
useEffect(()=>{ 
    if(selectedIssueGroup) 
      // modalPropsUpdate.onOpen() 
  }, [selectedIssueGroup]);
```

The error message says:

> expression expected.

I don't know what this means.

When I try to load the local host with this error, the error message is:

> Error:    x Unexpected token `}`. Expected this, import, async,
> function, [ for array literal, { for object literal, @ for decorator,
> function, class, null, true, false, number, bigint, string, regexp, `

I think Arjun might be expecting that I would put async and await somewhere in this solution, but I don't know where to put them.

> | for template literal, (, or an identifier

The onClick handler for update still has:

```
 onClick={() => {
     setSelectedIssueGroup(issueGroup)
     modalPropsUpdate.onOpen()
                           
 }}
```

**Second suggestion** - being to use value instead of defaultValue in the input fields.

When I try this, by removing defaultValue and adding: value={issueGroup?.title} to the inputs, the modal loads, with blank fields, but which update with the saved value when I click inside the input field.

However, I can't update the value even if this UX issue were okay (it isn't). The field becomes fixed and I can't type in it.

**Third suggestion** - being to define the defaultValues by using setValue. To implement this, I tried:

```
const { setValue } = useForm();
  
  
  const defaultValues = {
    title: setValue("title", selectedIssueGroup?.title),
    description: setValue("description", selectedIssueGroup?.description),
    // issues: "",
  }
  const form = useForm({ defaultValues, schema: IssueGroupSchema })
```

The modal loads (but with a blacked-out screen behind it, whereas other successful attempts just blur the background), but the saved values are not revealed in the input fields of the update form.

**SANDBOX**

I tried to make a sandbox for this form [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-frog-p72jji?file=/src/App.js). I don't know how to add the server connections to generate the types or mutations inside the code sandbox, so instead, I copied the prisma db extracts.

Comment: For the first suggestion, it asked to add `modalPropsUpdate` to add to dependency. You can do this like, `useEffect(()=>{ 
  if(selectedIssueGroup) 
    modalPropsUpdate.onOpen() 
}, [selectedIssueGroup,modalPropsUpdate]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try 1:

Possibly the state update completes after you open the modal because you wrote

```
setSelectedIssueGroup(issueGroup)
modalPropsUpdate.onOpen() // immediately opening modal
```

Here state update will take some time to set `selectedIssueGroup`. before that modal gets opened and you have `null` as default state value so you might get the error.

You need to open the modal once the state got set. You can achieve this using `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(()=>{ 
  if(selectedIssueGroup) 
    modalPropsUpdate.onOpen() 
}, [selectedIssueGroup]);
```

Try 2:

if your modal gets mounted to DOM even before opening it, then your `defaultValue` will be set null. In that case you have to use `value` prop in `<Input />` instead of `defaultValue` to set your values.

and handle null in input like

```
<Input name="title" label="Title" defaultValue={selectedIssueGroup?.title} />
```

Try 3:

you can get the `setValue` from `useForm()` like this,

```
const { setValue } = useForm();
```

and use it to set any field value with name

```
setValue("title", selectedIssueGroup.title);
```

Comment: Thank you for offering these suggestions. I tried each of them. I couldn't get any of them to work. I have updated the post to show how I tried to implement them. Thank you again.

Comment: Hey @Mel, if you can create a sandbox with your code and share it , i can help you address the issue.

Comment: Hi @Arjun, thank you. I tried making the useEffect the way you showed. It still doesn't work but I will make a codesandbox today. thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I tried to make a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-frog-p72jji?file=/src/App.js - i don't know how to add the backend to it. but the form is in the app

Comment: update your package.json and lib/graphql files on the sandbox you shared. Make sure the ui rendered without any error.